# Can't find package Tclx

Tags: tcl

When I run a tcl script in linux, the system return the error "can't find package Tclx"
[image]

I've checked the ActiveTcl-8.5/lib file, the Tcl8.5 exists.

[image]

Has anyone met it before? What can I do ?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are running ActiveState's tclsh?
tclsh is included in most Linux distributions, but TclX is not.

```
bll-tecra:bll$ which tclsh
/usr/bin/tclsh
bll-tecra:bll$ tclsh
% package require Tclx
can't find package Tclx
% exit
bll-tecra:bll$ /home/bll/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin/tclsh
% package require Tclx
8.4
% exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your help~I've fixed the error. the system indeed has no Tclx package. I execute  the command: teacup install Tclx. And now it's works.

Answer (score 3):

1. execute the command, link your Tcl installation to the new repository - pick any shell in your Tcl installation

   ```bash
   bash> teacup link make /path/to/new/repository /path/to/shell
   ```
2. install the package Tclx

   ```bash
   bash> teacup install Tclx
   ```
3. check the environment from within your Tcl shell:

   ```tcl
   % package require Tclx
   ```